# Poles of power series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

This may be a trivial question, but I haven't been able to find an answer.

Given a power series about $x_0$ $F(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (x-x_0)^n$, how do we find its (complex) poles? What about the degrees of those poles? Is there an explicit formula (analogous to the explicit formula for the radius of convergence) for the location and nature of the poles (and other singularities)?

Comment: Poles follow easily from the power series representation. I figure the only way you can ask this question is if you don't know the definition of pole.

Comment: @GitGud It's possible; what I mean by a pole is a point $x$ at which $F(x)$ goes to infinity. Is there an alternative, more easily applied definition of which I am unaware?

Comment: @Laertes Yes, you are right, I forgot that the series can diverge without having (a - z) in the denominator. I have deleted the answer.

Comment: @Laertes That's definition of a singularity. A pole is 'removable' when multiplied by an appropriate polynomial factor. Anyway, I realise now due to your comment in the deleted answer that in your question $F$ is one thing and the map $x\mapsto \sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty \left(a_n (x-x_0)^n\right)$ is another, so my comment is without effect.

Comment: So, will the definition by $\lim_{x\to x_0} (x-x_0)^nF(x)$ be ok? Like, if the limit exists, then the pole is of the $n-th$ degree (if $n = 0$, then there is no pole)?

Comment: @Igor That was essentially my thought, although I was also wondering whether we can have a pole of degree, say, $0.5$, or for instance a logarithmic pole, that is a point $x_0$ such that $\lim_{x\to x_0} \log\left(\frac x{x_0}\right)F(x)$ exists and is nonzero, or various combinations.

Comment: @Igor Something like that. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/774919/residue-calculation/774934#774934).

Answer (score 2):

I would say this is a very difficult thing to do (from which you can deduce that this is not going to be a very satisfactory answer...).

Having just the power series about one point, the radius of convergence tells you the distance from the point of expansion of the first point at which the function fails to be analytic. This essentially divides into poles, essential singularities, branch points, and the dreaded natural boundary (look up lacunary functions for the latter). (I've not seen a theorem stating these are the only options, but they're the only ones we normally mention. Should anyone have a reference for this sort of classification, I'm interested to see it.)

One thing that you can look up is [Padé approximants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant) (or [on Scholarpædia](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Pad%C3%A9_approximant)). (I admit these are a bit of a mystery to me as well, but they have an uncanny ability to put poles in the right places if the function has poles. If there's a branch cut, the process tends to add a line of poles and zeros along it in a direction tangential to the circle of convergence of the series, if I remember correctly.

The corresponding question for zeros is also difficult (Riemann hypothesis... and the Sendov conjecture).